# looping and iteration in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have a list data in Logstash that has been parsed as that looks like:

```
"Attribute": [

"<Book><Name>N1</Name><Value>Clement</Value></Book>",

"<Book><Name>N2</Name><Value>Bundle Name</Value></Book>"

],
```

I want to loop over that list to generate the following data in ouput:

```
"book1":{

"key": "N1",

"value":"Clement"

},

"book2":{

"key": "N2",

"value":"Bundle Name"
}
```

Is it possible to do that? 
Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can likely be done with [the `split {}` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html).

```
filter {
  split {
    field => "Attribute"
    target => "book_bundle"
    add_tags => [ "split_out" ]
  }
}
```

Which will take your source event, clone it into N new events, where N is the number of members of the `Attribute` array. The array member will be put into the `book_bundle` field, and the tag `split_out` added so you can tell it's already been split later down the filter stack.

Comment: "The array member will be put into the book_bundle field," Is there a timer to take this action? Because when I tried this filter, I found only the first member of the array..Then when I stop logstash process I found the rest of array's elements !

Comment: @M.MELKI You might try setting `periodic_flush =>` on this filter.

Comment: it works when I make periodic_flush => "true" .. Thank you very much !